# How to bind two datagrids with two different set data?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have two `data grids`. One will load a list of Diseases from Diseases table and one will load a list of Irritants from Irritants table. The problem is they have the same table names "Id", "Name", "Description" in my `database`. If (I think) I bind them, it might get ambiguous since they are in the same form. So aside from renaming the entire table in the `database`, is there any way to solve this, like specifying what table to bind in the mark up?

Here is for my Diseases table :

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IdColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DiseaseNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" MinWidth="250" />
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DiseaseDescriptionColumn" Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" MinWidth="250" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

And this is for my Irritants table :

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IdColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IrritantNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" MinWidth="250" />
    <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IrrirtantDescriptionColumn" Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" MinWidth="250" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: As long as you set `ItemsSource` to two different sources where each item will have `Id`, `Name` and `Description` you have no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply assign a different name to the 2 tables:

Diseases table:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="Diseases">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IdColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IrritantNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" MinWidth="250" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IrrirtantDescriptionColumn" Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" MinWidth="250" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Irritants table

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="Irritants">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IdColumn" Binding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" Visibility="Hidden"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IrritantNameColumn" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" MinWidth="250" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IrrirtantDescriptionColumn" Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" MinWidth="250" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
 <
```

In the code behind *.cs you add this code for load data in xaml grid

Diseases.ItemsSource = ARRAY_OR_LIST_OR_COLLECTION_OF_DISEAS;

Irritants.ItemsSource = ARRAY_OR_LIST_OR_COLLECTION_OF_IRRITANTS;